# JSP files are not showing <h2> after running spring-boot app

Tags: html, spring-boot, jsp

After running the application in tomcat embedded server I am being redirected to the login page which is only showing the login form. But in the login.jsp I have a  that contains a link to a registration form. This  is unseen when navigating to http://localhost:8080/login.
I have added a http://localhost:8080/registration but I am always redirected to the /login form

The controller:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Autowired
private ShopService shopService;

@Autowired
private SecurityService securityService;

@Autowired
private UserValidator userValidator;

@GetMapping("/registration")
public String registration(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("userForm", new User());

    return "registration";
}

@PostMapping("/registration")
public String registration(@ModelAttribute("userForm") User userForm, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    userValidator.validate(userForm, bindingResult);

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "registration";
    }

    userService.save(userForm);

    securityService.autoLogin(userForm.getUsername(), userForm.getPasswordConfirm());

    return "redirect:/welcome";
}

@GetMapping("/login")
public String login(Model model, String error, String logout) {
    if (error != null)
        model.addAttribute("error", "Your username and password is invalid.");

    if (logout != null)
        model.addAttribute("message", "You have been logged out successfully.");

    return "login";
}

@GetMapping({"/", "/welcome"})
public String welcome(Model model) {
    return "welcome";

}
```

the login JSP :

Log in

```
    <div class="form-group ${error != null ? 'has-error' : ''}">
        <span>${message}</span>
        <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"
               autofocus="true"/>
        <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"/>
        <span>${error}</span>
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>

        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Log In</button>
        <h2 class=text-center><a href="www.google.com">www.google.com</a></h2>
        <h4 class="text-center"><a href="${contextPath}/registration">Create an account</a></h4>
        <h2 class=text-center><a href="www.google.com">www.google.com</a></h2>

    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="${contextPath}/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It is strongly suggest NOT to use JSP. As they have severe limitations when using with embedded containers. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations

Comment: thank you but it did work properly before !

Comment: Also the title doesn't seem to match your problem. You should allow access to `/registration` to all users. You have probably enabled security for everything.

Comment: the /registration is permitted to all users according to the code below :
   
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/registration").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }